# Determine whether a subtree of a red-black tree has at most 3n/4 nodes?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree, recursive-datastructures

I have a red-black tree with `n` nodes, rooted at `x`. How can I prove or disprove that the number of nodes in the left subtree of `x` (including the root of `x.left`) is *at most* `3n / 4` without counting?

Answer (score 1):

You can just construct a counter-example with as many red nodes as possible on the left, and no red nodes at all on the right.

If the right is a complete all black tree with 2^h-1 nodes, and the left can be a complete tree with 2^(2h)-1 nodes.

When h>=3 the left side has more than 3n/4 nodes.

Comment: Wouldn't having no red nodes on the right violate the invariants of a red-black tree?

Comment: No, red nodes simply do not count in any way toward the height of a red-black tree. The invariance is that all paths from any particular node to all leaf nodes have the same number of black nodes.